# selecting a distinct primary key and getting a count of values for them

Tags: sql

I have a table that holds values like this,

```
menu_id       inner_text
1             Inner 1
1             Inner 2
2             Inner 1
2             Inner 2
2             Inner 3
3             Inner 1
```

I want to be able to select the menu_id distinctly and get a count of values that are present beside menu_id, for example

```
menu_id       count
1             2
2             3
3             1
```

I tried a few queries myself but not able to get the result I needed.
What do i do?

Comment: Give us the queries that you've tried and the output they produced.

Comment: 1. What database are you using? 2. You're looking for something called `GROUP BY`. Google it

Comment: @Yuushi I wasn't well aware of the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
SELECT MENU_ID,COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE
GROUP BY MENU_ID
```

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT menu_id, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY menu_id
ORDER BY menu_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select menu_id,count(*)
from table
group by menu_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your RDBMS, query might look like:

```
SELECT
    menu_id,
    COUNT(1)
FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY(menu_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT menu_id,COUNT(*) as count
FROM tablename
GROUP BY menu_id;
```